# Webbrowser com input type file

Tags: c#, asp.net, navegador-de-internet

Amigos, estou construindo um robô virtual para atuar em um determinado site.

Em uma determinada ação preciso fazer um upload de um arquivo para o site, mas quando o robô clica no botão `<input type="file">` logicamente abre uma janela modal do Windows Explorer.
Alguém pode me ajudar a FECHAR essa janela?
Pois já estou conseguindo fazer o upload mas o robô não continua enquanto não fecho a janela...

```html
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" size="80" tabindex="0" value="Procurar..." style="width:340px">
```

```cs
        HtmlElement fieldset = doc.GetElementsByTagName("fieldset")[4];
        HtmlElement input_ImpArq = fieldset.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
        input_ImpArq.InvokeMember("Click");                                  

        string caminho = "\\C:\\9000144.txt";
        SendKeys.Send(caminho + "{ENTER}");

        HtmlElement formulario = doc.GetElementById("formBusca");
        formulario.InvokeMember("submit");
```

Comment: Quando você escolhe o arquivo a janela não fecha automaticamente?

Answer (score 2):

Consegui realizar o que você precisa com ajuda [dessa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687876/uploading-files-not-working-need-assistance) no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) em inglês. O segredo está na utilização de `Task` com `Delay`:

Cria uma task assíncrona para pegar os controles e realizar o upload:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    HtmlElement fieldset = doc.GetElementsByTagName("fieldset")[4];
    HtmlElement input_ImpArq = fieldset.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
    await Upload(input_ImpArq);
}).ContinueWith(x =>
 {
     HtmlElement formulario = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("formBusca");
     formulario.InvokeMember("submit");
 }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Aqui  código do método que faz o upload:

```
async Task Upload(HtmlElement inputFile)
{
    inputFile.Focus();

    // atrasa a execução do ENTER para que a janela de seleçãp apareça
    var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
    {
        // isso é executado quando a janela está visível 
        SendKeys.Send(@"D:\teste.txt" + "{ENTER}");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    inputFile.InvokeMember("Click");

    await sendKeyTask;

    // aqui está o segredo, aguarda a janela de seleção de arquivp fechar
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

Você pode obter mais informações sobre execução assíncrona de `Task` em:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/async
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh191443.aspx